# Proof that Reuleaux triangles have constant width

Tags: geometry

All pages I read on Reuleaux triangles simply use a visual demonstration to illustrate this, but fail to make a rigorous argument. How might a formal proof of this fact proceed?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: It may not be immediately obvious, when the point-of-contact is not a vertex, that the sides adjacent to the opposite vertex do not reach higher than that vertex. (Indeed, if the sides had even *slightly* greater curvature, they would.) That the sides don't reach higher than the vertex can, of course, be assured by with a little angle chasing related to the tangents of those sides at that vertex.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: I don't think convexity is enough. If, say, only one of the sides has greater curvature, the figure would be convex, but not constant-width. (We'd also lose required symmetry, so this isn't a truly viable counterexample.) I believe the simplest thing to demonstrate is that, when the point of contact with the "floor" is not a vertex, the tangents at the opposite vertex point "floorward".

Comment: @Blue Thank you both for answering so promptly. I believe that invoking convexity is enough, but it still bothers me that this might not clearly address the issue.

Comment: @Blue thank you, I will try that approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Let $T$, on side $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$, be the point-of-contact with the horizontal "floor". Let $\overline{A^\prime C}$ be tangent to side $\stackrel{\frown}{BC}$ at $C$; necessarily, $\overline{AC}\perp \overline{A^\prime C}$. Likewise, $\overline{BC}\perp\overline{B^\prime C}$.

A little angle chasing shows that $\overline{A^\prime C}$ and $\overline{B^\prime C}$ make the same angle with the horizontal that $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BC}$, respectively, make with the vertical. Those angles are non-zero for $T$ strictly between $A$ and $B$, and zero at the endpoints. Consequently, the tangents slant "floorward", or one points horizontally, making $C$ the uppermost point of the figure. The figure's width is therefore $|CT|$, which, by construction, is the length of the side of equilateral $\triangle ABC$; that length is *constant*. $\square$

*edited

Comment: Awesome dude, thanks!